# How to avoid didSelectRowAtIndexPath being trigged when user tries to scroll bounce-disabled UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application, there's a View controller with bounce-disabled UITableView that covers the entire screen.

However, there is a situation where the table view contains only few items, which the sum of their heights is pretty equals to the screen's height.

As a result the table doesn't scroll (which is fine).

When the user tries to scroll in this situation, it triggers the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the start scrolling point. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can add some check in the delegate methods related to scrolling of TableView. May be this one is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to allow **bounce** effect :D 
Couldn't find any other solution :( 
to make a better experience make the bounce situational 
only allow tableView bounce if the (cellHeight * numberOfCells) < self.tableView.frame.size.height

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some sort of bug in framework (excuse me if it is not). I got this issue today morning and now I am not getting it.

Try adding the below line of code to the cell.

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

That is the only change I made to the tableview today, and not getting the issue any more. Reverting the change is not reintroducing the issue. Hence I am suspecting a framework issue.